# how to change default images in the theme of wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I just starting working on wordpress and I wanna change the default images in theme present on slider and other post.

I use that meta slider plugin as well but it didnt change the images on home page.

I'm new in wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestions are:

- [Select one of the themes that is suitable to your need](http://wordpress.org/themes/)
- [Create a child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)
- Head to personalize and choose customize from dash board

Answer (score 0):

if i didn't misunderstood, you could use random images function in your site. You can use exaltly different images in same/other pages. I am using in my site and it's very good and easy PHP trick.

Here is the link of [Simple Random Header Images](http://www.pearsonified.com/2006/10/simple_random_header_images_for_your_blog.php)...